# How do I create a Windows 10 bootable USB from Kali Linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, bootable-media, kali-linux

I deleted my recovery partition on accident when I was installing Kali. I've tried a method that was posted to this site, but I believe it only works for Windows 7. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to [this page on the Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10ISO)
2. Follow the instructions
3. Open a terminal in your downloads folder, and type the following commands. This will wipe your USB drive:

   `sudo dd if=filename-of-the-iso.iso of=/dev/sdX`

   Change the X to the letter for your usb. You can find the letter of your USB by running `df -H`, then plugging in your USB drive, then running it again, then the new line in it will have the /dev/sdX path. Do not include the number. Example: if `/dev/sdb1        11G  4.0G  6.8G  37% /media/ubuntu/PATRICK`
    is the new line, then the command is `sudo dd if=filename-of-the-iso.iso of=/dev/sdb`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35542/discussion-on-answer-by-geek1011-how-do-i-create-a-windows-10-bootable-usb-from).